# How to Set environment variable in tomacat8 installed through yum repo?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, yum

My java application expects some environment variables to run.
I had no problem in configuring the environment variables while using the tomcat8 which did not come through yum repo.

I used to follow these steps to inject environment variables in tomcatd while its starting

```
source env.sh
cd /opt/tomcat/bin
sudo -E ./startup.sh
```

These steps worked and I had no problem access the env variables from my java application

But In my new ec2 instance I have installed the tomcat through yum repo using this command `yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-admin-webapps`

After the installation I am not able to see the `startup.sh` file in the `bin` location (`/usr/share/tomcat8/bin`)

All I see is just 3 files

```
bootstrap.jar
catalina-tasks.xml
tomcat-juli.jar
```

How can I configure this tomcat8 installation  to use my environment variables while starting up ?

Comment: can u check as root "find / -name 'startup.sh' -type f"

Comment: Nothing Came up when I ran those commands :( @HRgiger

Comment: Prob it registered as service try "sudo systemctl status tomcat8" or "sudo systemctl status tomcat", i.e. if it is tomcat8 then set env values for service "sudo systemctl edit tomcat8", take a look at this question: https://serverfault.com/a/413408/228979, let me know if it works